# Decomposing pairs of run-lengths in NumPy

Tags: numpy

I am wondering whether the below-described function would be possible to implement quickly and efficiently in NumPy, or whether I would have to resort to Cython.

Let us say I have two vectors representing the runs in compressed run-length encodings. These do not have to be the same length. Furthermore, a run-length can never be zero.

```
r1 = np.array([1, 1, 3]) 
r2 = np.array([1, 3, 2])
```

I want a function that decomposes these and returns the lengths they share and the index in the respective array to the run that was decomposed.

Like

```
shared_runs, idx1, idx2 = f(r1, r2)

print(shared_runs)
# [1, 1, 2, 1, 1]
print(idx1)
# [0, 1, 2, 2, nan] # nan since the length of r1 is 5
print(idx2)
# [0, 1, 1, 2, 2]
```

`idx2` explained:

The first shared run has length 1, same as the first run of r2. Therefore the `shared_runs[0]` correspond to `r2[0]`. `shared_run[1]` has the value 1. However, `r2[1]` has value 3. Therefore both `idx2[1]` and `idx2[2]` points to 1, since the `shared_run[1]` and `shared_run[2]` together decompose the value 3.

Further examples:

```
r1 = np.array([5])
r2 = np.array([1])

# [1, 4], [0, 0], [0, nan]

r1 = np.array([3, 2, 1])
r2 = np.array([1, 4])

# [1, 2, 2, 1], [0, 0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 1, nan]
```

Comment: please explain how `idx1` and `idx2` are computed. Or just paste "slow" algorithm used to compute it

Comment: I had an error in my example. Updated with an explanation! I must run now, will look at after the weekend. Feedback on how I can improve my q appreciated.

Comment: For the new example where `r1 = [5]` and `r2 = [1]`, shouldn't `idx1` be `[0, 0]`?

Comment: Yes, sorry! I wrote the question at the end of the week. Should have waited till Monday XD